# Require deletion reason

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

Can we require a deletion reason to be entered any time an OP deletes their post, question or answer?

I think this would help moderators (including 10k users) get answers when asked to explain a "why".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Why bother?*

Posts can be deleted for all sorts of reasons, but I can't think of a single one where it would actually affect my view of the post, and even if it did, I can't imagine what I could do differently. I mean, yeah, sure, maybe *sometimes* it would resolve a curiosity, but I can't think of a single time I've seen a deleted post and, five minutes after closing it, cared enough to wish the user had explained their deletion reason. It's generally pretty clear, or not a big deal.

On top of that, if we required reason, people would feel all the more trapped, or inclined not to self-police straight-up bad content. We all know that content is immediately licensed away from us when we post it on Stack Exchange (that sounds hostile, it's not meant to be, it's a good thing), but it's still nice to think we have *some* control over what sticks around. There are obvious exceptions, like when there are up-voted answers. But for the post part, it's nice to be able to freely delete something without having to do extra work just to be able to.

If a user is posting tons of great things, then immediately deleting them, that would be an edge-case, worthy of perhaps a comment (or maybe, **maybe** a mod-message if it was causing trouble and consistent enough) asking for a reason. But that doesn't seem like it would ever happen, let alone would it happen often enough to warrant an entire system being put in place, then being enforced, that asks "why are you deleting this" on every post.

A post being deleted is a reflection generally of that post, and not of the user. I can see where you'd be coming from if this were about deleting an *account*, because that would probably mean they had an issue, perhaps even one that could be addressed, with Stack Exchange or the way something works. But I've deleted posts in my life just because I messed up or didn't comprehend something, and forcing me to write something to address a curiosity just doesn't seem worth it.

Answer (score 1):

An on-hold closed question (not migrated, not a duplicate) has only two possible destinations (putting aside the aberration that is the extremely rare "historical lock").

A closed question can be re-opened, or deleted.

So every delete vote already implies the "why": the question is not good enough (quality, on-topicness, answerability, appropriate level) to be reopened.

Hence, entering a deletion reason would be redundant.

Furthermore, almost all sites that I've seen (except Academia, where we have an active ongoing cleanup) have a large proportion of closed questions that are getting neither re-opened nor deleted - e.g it's about 7% currently on Physics, and I've seen it above 10%. Adding an extra little hurdle, such as requiring a deletion reason, would just make that worse.